# Date time functions help informix

Tags: sql, date, informix

How can I use the date add or date diff functions I have a scenario where I need find people whose birthdays are either today or after n number of days. How can I achieve it in informix.

```
SELECT mbr_code, fname, lname
INTO rsMbrCode, rsFName, rsLName
FROM asamembr
WHERE cust_code = membershipnumber 
    AND ((day(bdate) - day(CURRENT)) <= rsTest 
    AND MONTH(bdate) = month(CURRENT))

RETURN rsMbrCode, rsFName, rsLName WITH RESUME;
```

Answer (score 8):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT mbr_code,fname,lname
INTO rsMbrCode,rsFName,rsLName
FROM asamembr
WHERE cust_code = membershipnumber 
    AND MDY(month(bdate),day(bdate),year(today)) 
    BETWEEN TODAY AND TODAY + <NUMBEROFDAYS> UNITS DAY;
```

You construct a date with Using MDY with the `MONTH` and `DAY` from `bdate` and `YEAR` from `TODAY`. Then you see if it is between the dates you want to match.

[Documentation for MDY](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v115/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1541.htm):

> The MDY function takes as its arguments three integer expressions that
>   represent the month, day, and year, and returns a type DATE value.
>
> - The first argument represents the number of the month (1 to 12).
> - The second argument represents the number of the day of the month (1 to 28, 29, 30, or 31, as appropriate for the month)
> - The third expression represents the 4-digit year. You cannot use a 2-digit abbreviation.